# QTableWidget - context menu only for specific cells/columns

Tags: c++, qt4, contextmenu, qtablewidget

I am using a QTableWidget for displaying data. I know that I can use the addAction method to add a context menu. How can I limit the context menu to only specific cells or columns? addAction exists for QActionGroup QGraphicsWidget QMenu QMenuBar QToolBar QWidget. Should I somehow filter oder disable/enable the signal/slots? Work with right click events?

A similar question would be how to get different context menu's for different rows?

Thank you and cheers,
Matthias

Comment: You are strongly recommended to use the MVC method for tables. It will also allow you to customize context menus elegantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method to create custom context menus is to implement a slot to the `QWidget::customContextMenuRequested()` signal. There you can query the cell under the position (`QTableWidget::itemAt()` - watch out for global->widget mapping!), and then build a custom menu using `QMenu` and `QAction`.

Also, I'd build the menu(s) beforehand, and than only exec() it in the slot.

Remember that you have to change the `QWidget::ContextMenuPolicy` property of the widget to `Qt::CustomContextMenu`!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That sound's good. Unfortunately I could not bring it up to work. `TableView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);` and   `connect( TableView, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested() ),
    this, SLOT( on_TableView_ContextMenuRequest() ) );` were added; and of course the slot declared and implemented. Break point is not jumped at and message box for testing does not appear.

Comment: Ok, it is `(const QPoint &)`, so `connect( TableView, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &) ),
    this, SLOT( on_TableView_ContextMenuRequest() ) );` would be right. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, let's say this is finally right and makes more sense: `connect( TableView, SIGNAL( customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &) ),
    this, SLOT( on_TableView_ContextMenuRequest(const QPoint &) ) );`